# Determining when order of a set of columns changes in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a very large csv file with following structure:

```
  a1  b1  c1 a2 b2 c2 a3 b3 c3 ..... a999 b999 c999    
0 5   4   2  3  2  2  6  7  9  ....................
1 2   1   4  4  6  9  3  5  9  ....................
.
.
```

What I want to do is to group the columns in sets of N, for a, b and c, and check when the index of maximum value (argmax) of the set changes, in each row.

So in the above example, for N = 3, a1, b1, c1 is the first set in row 0, and argmax is 0, 2nd set is a2, b2, c2 and argmax is still 0, 3rd set is a3, b3, c3 but now the argmax is 2. I deally I am looking for a script that parses the whole csv file and returns [c3, c1]. c3 because thats where the argmax changes in row 0 and c1 becuase argmax doesn't change in row 1 but c1 is the largest value in that set.

I am doing this right now by using two for loops and its slow and looks very ugly, is there a better pandas pythonic way of doing this? I feel there must be.

Comment: a combination of transpose and groupby should do the trick, if I find some spare time I'll give it a go

Comment: What do you mean `c is the largest value in that set`. Do you mean `c1` because the maximum value always occurs in `c` and so you take the first set?

Comment: @ALollz - Exactly

Answer (score 0):

You can `groupby` sets of columns and use `.idxmax` to find the column where the maximum occurs within each set. You can find where the first letter changes (if it ever does) to get your list.

```
n = 3
df2 = df.groupby([x//n for x in range(len(df.columns))], axis=1).idxmax(1)

mask = df2.applymap(lambda x: x[0])  # Case of 1-letter column prefix
## If possibility of words with different length ending in digits try
# import string 
# mask = df2.applymap(lambda x: x.strip(string.digits))

df2.lookup(df2.index, 
           (mask.ne(mask.shift(-1, axis=1)).idxmax(1)+1) % (len(mask.columns))).tolist()
```

---

#### Sample Data

```
print(df)
   a1  b1  c1  a2  b2  c2  a3  b3  c3
0   5   4   2   3   2   2   6   7   9
1   2   1   4   4   6   9   3   5   9
2   2   1   4  10   6   9   3   5   9
3   2   1   4   1   6   9   3  10   9

n = 3
df2 = df.groupby([x//n for x in range(len(df.columns))], axis=1).idxmax(1)
print(df2)
#    0   1   2
#0  a1  a2  c3
#1  c1  c2  c3
#2  c1  a2  c3
#3  c1  c2  b3

mask = df2.applymap(lambda x: x[0])
df2.lookup(df2.index, (mask.ne(mask.shift(-1, axis=1)).idxmax(1)+1) % (len(mask.columns))).tolist()
#['c3', 'c1', 'a2', 'b3']
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to keep to code as simple as possible. You can translate your dataframe and group by the sliced column name:

```
df = df.T.reset_index()
idx = df.groupby(df['index'].str.slice(1,2)).idxmax()
```

Output:

```
       0  1
index      
1      0  2
2      3  5
3      8  8
```

That means that for row 0 the max for group 1 is at index 0, the max group 2 is at index 3 (or 0 is you take the mod 3), the max for group 3 is at index 8, (or 2 if you take mod 3). Same reading for row 1 :)

If you need the actual column name:

```
df.columns[idx.values.flatten(order='F')]
```

Output:

```
['a1', 'a2', 'c3', 'c1', 'c2', 'c3']
```